# How to read a json on swift with null keys and using default values?

Tags: json, decode, default-value, swift5

I have a class defined as:

```
struct MyObject: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var paramA: String
    var paramB: String
    var paramC: String

    init(paramA: String, paramB: String = "default", paramC: String = "tomato"  ){
        self.paramA = paramA
        self.paramB = paramB
        self.paramC = paramC
    }
}
```

For read the Json Im using landmarkData

```
let landmarkData: [Landmark] = load("inputData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {  
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

I've decided that the data can also come through a Json, so I changed the structure of MyObject (adding Hashable, Codable and changing var id = UUID() for Int and move to parameter)

```
struct MyObject: **Hashable, Codable**, Identifiable{
    **var id = Int**
    var paramA: String
    var paramB: String
    var paramC: String

    init(**id : Int,** paramA: String, paramB: String = "default", paramC: String = "tomato"  ){
        **self.id = id**
        self.paramA = paramA
        self.paramB = paramB
        self.paramC = paramC
    }
}
```

This works with a Json with all the keys on each object. But I would like to not define the keys that will take a default value(paramA and paramB keys). And I don't have to define the id in the Json.

**inputData.json**

```
 [{
    "paramA": "Hello",
    "paramB": "World",
    "paramC": "!!!",
 },
 {
    "paramA": "Hi",
 },
 {
    "paramA": "Hello",
    "paramC": "??",
 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked by adding a decoder int and a try for the cases that could not bring the key.  I don't know if there's a better solution.

```
struct MyObject: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var paramA: String
    var paramB: String
    var paramC: String

    init(paramA: String, paramB: String = "default", paramC: String = "tomato"  ){
        self.paramA = paramA
        self.paramB = paramB
        self.paramC = paramC
    }

 init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .paramA)

       do {
            paramB = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .paramB)
          }
          catch {
            paramB = "default"
          }

       do {
            paramC = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .paramC)
          }
          catch {
            paramC = "default"
          }
}
```